# Possible to render an app without tranditional window controls

Tags: uwp

I'm looking to build a UWP app that potentially renders fullscreen, and then shrinks down to a small overlay. For an idea of what I'm talking about, see the app [demonstrated here](https://getslash.co/).

I'm pretty new to Windows development - is something like this possible with UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this currently isn't possible with UWP! The solution appears to be to make a WPF application and host a UWP UI using a XAML Island, as outlined in [this blog post](https://stefanwick.com/2018/12/19/creating-chromeless-non-rectangular-windows-from-uwp/).